# What is important when taking a professional profile picture?

Tags: portrait

What considerations are especially important when taking a headshot for a professional networking site such as LinkedIn? Obviously, all normal good photography techniques apply, but are there any specific concerns for professional profile pictures?

Comment: As a specific consideration for a social networking site, consider that the profile images are invariably to the left of their name / text.  So having them (or their body at least) facing to the right means they're looking 'into' their content.

Comment: @James: Good point, but that means the person in the picture should be looking to their *left*, not right.

Comment: Just putting a real headshot there instead of thumbing your nose at everyone else by putting a picture of your cat, some silly cartoon character, etc, will already put you ahead of the majorit there.

Answer (score 7):

Remove distractions from the background, make sure to nail focus on the eyes, ensure proper soft attractive lighting, and use a lens that is both sharp and flattering for portrait photography.

Lots of tutorials and examples exist, search for "headshots":

- http://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-take-the-perfect-headshot-six-tips
- http://www.colemanphotographix.com/take-professional-headshots-yourself/
- http://fstoppers.com/peter-hurleys-google-keynote-how-to-take-the-perfect-headshot

Comment: Hurley's advice should be at the top of the list. A trained monkey can do the mechanical photography part (generations of "school picture" types working for minimum wage and shooting 20-30 kids/minute have proved that quite thoroughly); the hard part is bringing the subject to life. "10% photographer, 90%  therapist" is about right.