# Looking for tips for a good LinkedIn profile picture session

Tags: portrait, indoor, headshot, on-location

I'm new in this site and in photography as well.

I don't have professional equipment (nor budget), but I think my gear is just enought for what I want to accomplish.

I want to gather some experience within my inner circle - and hopefully beyond that-  in a niche market: LinkedIn's profile picture.

So, here I am, looking for experiences, recomendations, etc about gear, lighting, post processing, how to give directions during sessions, how to contact clients,... any advise is welcome.

My gear:
Olympus PEN E-PL5 with a 45mm f1.8 lens
3 Remote flashes, light stand, shoot through umbrella, small softbox, reflector and a tripode.

Thanks

EDIT: I'm adding thing I already readed to help others

[Tips for creating attractive and useful head-shot style avatars](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/tips-for-creating-attractive-and-useful-head-shot-style-avatars?rq=1)

[What is important when taking a professional profile picture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30538/what-is-important-when-taking-a-professional-profile-picture?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should be considered for employee photos to put on company's website?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11729/what-should-be-considered-for-employee-photos-to-put-on-companys-website)

Comment: @MichaelClark Thanks for the link, but it seems partial considering the things I'm asking. It's more or less in the same line of answer I've already commented above.

Comment: I voted to Leave Open but I was awfully close to voting close. I think you might get the answer you want by concentrating on how a LinkedIn photo would be different from a regular corporate head shot. Personally I have no idea how they would be different aside from aspect ratio possibly.

Comment: And your question is WAY too broad, combining lighting and marketing in the same question? No, but the basic question is possibly interesting.